# how to remove text field border in phoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am tried to user form details i have Text-Fields create like this

```
 <div  data-role="fieldcontain" class="name">
<label for="email"> <font color="white">No of lights</font> </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="one" type="text" style="background-color:#686868" name="Name" />


 </div>
```

it showing like this
[image]

but i want  like this [image]

so I can applied like

```
.one{
border-left:none;
border-top:none;
border-right:none;

}
```

but it's not works my Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<style>
.one{
border-left:none;
border-top:none;
border-right:none;
}
#pageone{

background-color:#666666;
}
</style>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="a" >
 <div  data-role="fieldcontain" class="name">
<label for="email"> <font color="white">No of lights</font> </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="one" type="text" style="background-color:#686868" name="Name" />
</div>

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Please give me any Idea about how to remove Text-Field Borders 
And Please Tell me What are changes in our code

Answer (score 1):

```
input.one{
background-color: transparent; 
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; 
border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: try this: input.one{
background-color: transparent; 
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; 
border-color: white;
}

Comment: border-color applied  on bottom  but left and right and top border are not Removed

Comment: Could you give a link to your project!? @user3488098

Comment: it's not project  jest i create login page but 
my Problem is create text fields and Image one i got output but i think like second image output  so Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
input{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    outline: none;
}
```

Add outline so that when the textbox is selected, the outline border does not gets visible.

Comment: please tell me and what fiddle

Comment: my Problem is How remove the Top,Left and right borders 
But when remove 4Lines 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 

it's work but i want this 4 lines

Comment: you'r code work when remove head part in my code but header part will be used in Future so With out remove header part i tried

Comment: Thats why i said, please share a fiddle so that i can know if my code is working fine or not

Comment: The link is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

In phonegap input tag is enclosed in div tag.
for example:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
  <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="" type="text">
</div>
```

So you can change the classes "ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" and can remove the border.